# Registration new user – create new database Wordpress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have a request about creating a new database when a new user creates his own account. I’m creating a portal with a lot of records per user and 6-7 tables, so I think using one database for all users would be very slow. Is this possible?

I have Wordpress 4.8.1 and MySQL database

Comment: Why do you think one database will be very slow? And the answer to your question is "yes" but that doesn't give much information. I assume you're asking "how", not "is it possible", in which case please edit the question and explain more.

Comment: Ok, my question is "how". One user will have from 1 to 100 objects with a few happenings. Won't it not slow down? It will be safer to give an access only to your data, won't it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is outside the scope of Stack Overflow. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) It is expected that you have done proper research and made attempts to solve it before posting, and questions should include a summary of what you have tried so far and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and come back when you have a specific coding question to ask.